# Finding $z$ in the form $a+bi$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to solve
$$3z + 17i = iz + 11$$
and write $z$ in the form $a+bi$.

I substituted $a+bi$ for $z$ and got two simultaneous equations.
$$3a+b = 11,\quad
a-3b = -17$$
But am not getting the same answer. The answer is $z=5-4i$

Answer (score 1):

$$3z + 17i = iz + 11$$
$$(3-i)z= 11- 17i$$
$$z=\frac{11-17i}{3-i}$$
Now multiply the numerator and denomerator by the conjugate of the denomaretor and separate the real and imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

$$3z+17i=iz+11$$

substituting $z=a+ib$,

$$ 3(a+ib)+17i=i(a+ib)+11$$

$$ 3a +3bi+17i=ai-b+11$$

$$3a+i(3b+17)=(11-b)+ai$$

Equating real part to real and imaginary part to imaginary part.

$3a=11-b$ and $a=3b+17$. Now you have two equations and two variables. I shall let you conclude now.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to solve the system of equations

$$3a+b=11$$
$$a-3b=17$$

Using elimination techniques,

$$3a+b=11$$
$$3a-9b=51$$

Which implies

$$10b=-40$$

Can you go from there?

Answer (score 0):

$$3z+17i=iz+11 \Rightarrow z(3-i)=11-17i$$

$$ z=\frac{11-17i}{3-i}=\frac{(11-17i)(3+i)}{(3-i)(3+i)}=\frac{50-40i}{10}=5-4i$$